# LibGDX camera following player with TiledMap?

Tags: java, camera, libgdx

I am attempting to set the camera to focus on the player in the center, as it goes over a TiledMap fixed in place. I am using this rendering code for the camera:

```
OverworldWorld world;
Player player;
OrthographicCamera cam;
SpriteBatch batch;
TiledMap map;
TileAtlas tileAtlas;
TileMapRenderer tmr;

public Renderer(OverworldWorld world){
    this.world = world;

    world.setRenderer(this);

    width = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    height = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

    new TiledLoader();
    map = TiledLoader.createMap(Gdx.files.internal("maps/island.tmx"));
    tileAtlas = new TileAtlas(map, Gdx.files.internal("maps/"));
    tmr = new TileMapRenderer(map, tileAtlas, 16, 16);

    cam = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    cam.setToOrtho(false, width, height);
    cam.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    cam.update();

    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.projection);

    sr = new ShapeRenderer();


}

public void render(){
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    player = world.getPlayer();

    cam.position.set(player.getPosition().x, player.getPosition().y, 0);
    cam.update();

    tmr.getProjectionMatrix().set(cam.combined);

    Vector3 tmp = new Vector3();
    tmp.set(0, 0, 0);
    cam.unproject(tmp);
    tmr.render((int) tmp.x, (int) tmp.y, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
```

The result is that the player is locked to the bottom left corner of the map, and moving the player moves the camera over the map. The movement is pretty basic:

```
player = world.getPlayer();
    switch(keycode){
    case Keys.W:
        player.getVelocity().y = 1;
        player.direction = "up";
        break;
```

and updating the player position uses this (this is with version 0.9.8):

```
position.add(velocity.tmp().mul(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() * speed));
```

What is causing this issue, and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Not sure why your sprite isn't moving, i'm working on it... however if you want the camera centered directly over the player, you should add half his width, and half his height to his position and pass that to the camera as LIBGDX typically renders a sprite from the bottom left corner up.

Comment: The player starts centered over the camera, but is always in the same spot relative to the map, and when the player "moves", the camera moves over the map, sending the player off-center.

Answer (score 3):

I will try my best to explain the one way I know to implement this, so sorry if this is not helpful.

You need to be able to get your players current XY. getX(), getY(). You can add this manually to your player class. Once you have access, all you need to do is start the camera empty, and set the camera position to the players XY,  his width, height and some small division. This would look like this.

```
@Override
public void create() {      


    cam = new OrthographicCamera();


}
```

This will work on the create(), resize(), or show() methods.

And finally we render the camera and get the coordinates.

```
@Override
public void render() {      
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.294f, 0.294f, 0.294f, 1f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    cam.position.set(viewer.getX() + viewer.getWidth() / 2, viewer.getY() + viewer.getHeight() / 2, 0);
    cam.viewportWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / viewer.getZoom();
    cam.viewportHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / viewer.getZoom();

    cam.update();

}
```

So in simple math.

(players current X + players current width / 2) for x and (players current Y + players current height / 2) for y

The lines after that is an example of how to zoom the camera using a float stored in the player class.

```
cam.viewportWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / viewer.getZoom();
    cam.viewportHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / viewer.getZoom();
```

Using this code you could easily make the camera zoom in and out as the character gains speed.

I hoped this helped.